# Unexpected non-void return value in void function swift 4 using json serialisation

Tags: swift

I am currently trying to clean up my code on a project by writing a generic function that can be used multiple times. However i need my function to return an array. My error is "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Here is my code

```
func JSONSerialisation(JsonUrl: String) -> NSArray{
    let url = URL(string: JsonUrl)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, responce, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")

        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    if let Json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSArray{
                        return Json //Error occurs here
                    }

                }
                catch
                {

                }

            }

        }

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

There are a few questions like this on Stack Overflow but so far none of them have been able to fix my problem as they all say add `-> NSArray`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Won't work anyway because your method is `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:)` is asynchronous. Use a closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't return data directly from an asynchronous task. Use a closure**

Create a Function using a closure like.

```
func jsonSerialisation(jsonUrl: String, completion block: @escaping ((NSArray) -> ())){
    let url = URL(string: JsonUrl)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, responce, error) in
        if let e = error{
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }
        else{
            if let content = data{
                do {
                    if let Json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSArray{
                        block(Json)
                    }
                }
                catch let error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And Call :

```
jsonSerialisation(jsonUrl: "Your Url") { (json) in
    print(json)
}
```

This is helpful